# How to perform a task on selecting spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to exectute Async task on selecting a spinner item and add some data to another spinner. It works well if i select a item. But it automatically executes AsyncTask even when not selecting. This is what i have tried

```
    district
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        ssservice));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        district
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                               View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      //  ed_spinner = district.getSelectedItem().toString();
                       new NetCheck2().execute();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
```

How to execute Async Task only after I click on spinner item. Please help me.

Comment: user onitemclick listener instead of onitemselected listener

Comment: @AnandSavjani OnItemClickeListener() cannot be used with spinner

Comment: i am using `spinner.setOnItemClickListener` . So you can't say that its cannot be used with spinner

Comment: Set a title which cant be selected using custom spinner layout so on first time load no item will be selected hence no async task.

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu How can I set title for spinner??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spinner is badly designed. Unfortunately when you call `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener` it automatically calls `onItemSelected`. This is not a problem with your code, the spinner is designed that way. I know its bad, but this is how it works.

**Workaround**

If suppose your spinner has 4 entries, add one more entry at top i.e. 0th position and now when spinner is created `onItemClicked` is called and it will have position 0. So just put a if condition that

```
if (!(position == 0)){//do your stuff}
```

Comment: What if the user selects position say 5th item and  on second try selects first item ? it should still execute async task i am afraid it wont on this logic

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu no, we already filtered that in if condition.

Comment: @deepu513 If I select first item async task is not executed

Comment: @Priyanka yes because of the condition, Use Your first Item for the Purpose of the list Title which is not the part of the actual data.

Comment: @JaiminModi I am getting data in spinner from another async task so if add title it gets replaced

Comment: @DhinakaranThennarasu I have added solution. Hope it will be as per your thought.

Comment: @Priyanka If your spinner data is coming from another AsyncTask, you need to add an item at 0th position at runtime.
I assume `ssservice` is your `ArrayList`, so before calling `setAdapter` do this: `ssservice.add(0,"Select item")` This will add an item at 0th position at runtime.

Comment: though its better this way, from user perspective he should not be able to select "Select item" in the spinner. but he would be able to do so in this case..just saying ;P